# Display Customized image in place of Base image under "Recently added items"

Tags: magento-1.9, image

Once user Uploaded custom image on [Product image](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) & Add item to cart, than we want to display **custom image** below "**Recently added items**" instead of normal product image.

[image]

**custom uploaded image** :

[image]

we are saving custom image in path : **media/custom_options/quote** .
custom image path in table : "**sales_flat_quote_item_option**" in column : "**value**"

[image]

**1.code** to display normal product image :

app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml

```
<!--Custom product image code -->

<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); 
$_product = $this->getProduct();

if($_product->getAttributeSetId()==9)
{
    // code for display custom image    
}

else
{

?>

<!--Normal product image code -->

<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>
```

I tried below **code** , but its not displaying custom image under Recently added items : Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_**Renderer.php**

```
protected function _getImageSrc($optionValue)
    {
        if(file_exists($optionValue['fullpath']))
        {
            $pathNew = str_replace(DS.'media'.DS.'custom_options', '', $optionValue['order_path']);
            $image = Mage::getModel('aitcg/image');
            $image->copyImage($optionValue['fullpath'], $image->getEmailPath().$pathNew);
            return $image->getEmailUrl().$pathNew;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

As we are saving custom image in path : **media/custom_options/quote** how to display that custom image under "Recently added items".....

Comment: from where exactly you are getting that customized image tag ?

Comment: @GopalPatel please  visit [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4s.html#) and `upload image` and `save design` and `add to cart` and go for cart page.... in cart page you can see both normal and customized image....

Comment: Looks like they are storing image as product option

Comment: @GopalPatel please help me to display same image below `Recently added items` also.....

Comment: Find the code from where they are creating div with `id=""preview_container899967386" //any number` on cart page. may be they are storing something into quote object

Comment: @GopalPatel let me search that code

Comment: @GopalPatel i didt got any code file when i searched for complete word  `preview_container899967386` , but i got some files as in these images when i searched for  `preview_container`  http://prnt.sc/e8hqh3  http://prnt.sc/e8hqhm

Comment: but i got the file  its `rwd/stylebaby/template/aictg/view/options/type/cgfile.phtml`

Comment: @GopalPatel  thats really great, please check that file code : http://pastebin.com/ssDdPmBT

Comment: after dig into your code got one function which play important role `htmlEscape` function in  `Aitoc_Aitcg_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Options_Type_File` you have to know the entire function of this extension.

Comment: @GopalPatel Thanks for your time for looking the complete code....  when i checked this file,  i did't saw `htmlEscape` function, can you please check code : here is code of 

`app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitcg/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Options/Type/file.php` : http://pastebin.com/cdG2binY

Comment: hey `Do you getting ` $optionValue['order_path'] at cart page?

Comment: @AmitBera seems i am not getting , let me check related cart page code once again and i will inform you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your **app/design/frontend/rwd/Stylebaby/template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml** file with below code,

```
<?php 
$customImage = '';
$quoteOptions = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
if(!empty($quoteOptions['info_buyRequest']['options'][132]["quote_path"])){
    $customImage = $quoteOptions['info_buyRequest']['options'][132]["quote_path"];
}
?>
```

Now update your image code with below.

```
<?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image">
    <?php if($customImage == ''){ ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
    <?php } else { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().$customImage; ?>" width="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
    <?php }
    ?>
    </a>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="product-image">
    <?php if($customImage == ''){ ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
    <?php } else { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().$customImage; ?>" width="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
    <?php }
    ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: let me check and get back to you.....

Comment: Thanks , almost working fine, need to replace image icon with real image.....

Answer (score 3):

Save custom image in database table and for cart page. Modify the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer.php` (rewrite class)
override `getProductThumbnail()` and apply your saved custom image instead of default product image.

Comment: thanks, please update answer with code according to my requirements......

Comment: If u save image in database table sales_flat_quote_item, u will be able to get that image from item object ($this->getItem()). Then check that if the product is added after cutomizaation then return custom image and other wise return product image.

Comment: please check updated question......

Answer (score 2):

In phtml displaying products in cart you have to add own logic for displaying base image.
By default it is in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml`

or 
`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\render\default(or simple).phtml`

But on your store it should be in different theme.

There is line 33 :

```
<td><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><?php endif;?><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?></a><?php endif;?></td>
```

and inside:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
```

code `<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75); ?>` respond for displaying image product.
You should make some logic checking in current product have custom design and depends on it display base image (thumbnail) or custom (design).

Also remove display image from recently added

Comment: Thanks , i am trying `if($_product->getAttributeSetId()==9)` this condition to display custom product image. but i am struck in what code is i need to use to display custom image under `recently added items`.....

Answer (score 1):

I done this functionality and successfully working in my project. Below are the steps for it.

1. I added two column named as **"custom_image"** and **"custom_flag"** in table **sales_flat_quote_item** and **sales_flat_order_item**
2. Set image source into hidden field in **product_addtocart_form** form. Using submit event of form I set value of image source into hidden filed.
3. I used event **"checkout_cart_add_product_complete"** and in this event I get all post data including that image source in hidden field. 
   Hidden field name is **download_image_data**. I created one folder **tmpcartprodimg** inside media. Add below code in observer.

   ```
   $product_id     = $this->_getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
   $currentDate    = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H_i_s');

   $cart   = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
   $quote  = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
   $quote_item =  Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($quote->getItemByProduct($observer->getEvent()->getProduct())->getId());
   $quote_id   = $quote_item->getItemId();

   foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
       if(($item->getProductId() == $product_id) && ($quote_id == $item->getId())) {
           $cart_id = $item->getId();
           $product_img    = md5($item->getProductId().$currentDate);
           Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
           $sales_quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($item->getId());
           $sales_quote->setId($item->getId());
           $sales_quote->setData($item->getData());
           $sales_quote->setData('custom_flag' , 1);
           $sales_quote->setData('custom_image' , $product_img.".png");
           $sales_quote->save(); 
           // Convert hidden value into image and store into tmpcartprodimg folder
           $image_base64_data  = $this->_getRequest()->getPost('download_image_data');
           $image_base64_data  = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $image_base64_data));
           $prod_image_name    = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS ."tmpcartprodimg". DS . $product_img .'.png';
           file_put_contents($prod_image_name, $image_base64_data);
       }
   }
   ```

4) You will get data of custom_image and custom_flag in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml` by `$_item->getCustomImage()`
You can write your code dispaly this image from tmpcartprodimg folder.

5) When quote will convert into order that time this fields need to be move into sales_flat_order_item table. You need to write code for it.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, custom image is already saving in db , all i need is to fetch that custom image and display in frontend. i need help for this.....

Comment: Write code to get custom option value of image and replace it with product image in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml`